# Exercises for "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science: Principles and Elementary Applications"

Tags: probability, reference-request, probability-theory

I am learning [Probability Theory: The Logic of Science](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0521592712/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=067J3K1VND6GXSQPZH3P&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=317828027&pf_rd_i=468294), the most famous probability book.

But it seems this book doesn't provide any exercises, but **I do need some to test myself to see whether I really understand or not**.

So any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest Ross' *A First Course in Probabiliy*. Or, for an online text with problem sets, [this one](http://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf). Of course, a Google search would reveal other sources for problem sets.

Comment: *the most famous probability book*... Sorry to disappoint you but the crown (if any) might rather go to Feller's two volumes treatise.